# Using Geocoding in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I used maps and geocoding in android using google maps . Presently i am developing a project in windows phone 8.

Let me know which is the best method or setting maps and locating positions with path from the current location using longitude and latitude.

pls give me some suggestion or links .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get started, check "[Maps and navigation for Windows Phone
   8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207045%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)" article series from MSDN. The series consist of :

- [How to add a Map control to a page in Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207033%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- [How to show your current location on a map in Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735578%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- [How to display route and directions on a map in Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244363%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- [How to add UIElements to a Map control in Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207037%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- [How to request driving or walking directions for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj710324%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- [How to respond to requests for directions for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj851121%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

"*Let me know which is the best method or setting maps and locating positions with path from the current location using longitude and latitude.*"

Check third article in the series above if you want to display Maps including the route inside your app. Otherwise, you have easier option by using [Maps direction task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207044%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) that will launch built-in Maps.